# Exception thrown while uploading file on FTP server from Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ftp

I want to upload a video file on FTP server, my all search results ended to MSDN managzine article [Adding FTP Support in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn385710.aspx). It has awesome example & library. I tried 2 FTP URLs, one is Mozilla repository & another is my confidential URL. Nothing worked for me but throws exception. I tried my FTP URL in an app called [File Downloader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/file-downloader/09b457ef-e283-4a37-896a-894e92911584), it worked correctly. Expcetion details & output windows log is given below.

Thus, any one can suggest me what should I do changes in that library? Is there another working library available or any other way to upload file to FTP?

```
Exception is thrown in file FtpClient.cs, event FtpClientSocket_DataReceived(...), at line "await PrepareDataChannelAsync(Response);" [Line # 253]

ftp.mozilla.org

System.Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274C)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WinPhoneFtp.FtpService.FtpClient.<PrepareDataChannelAsync>d__2b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WinPhoneFtp.FtpService.FtpClient.<FtpClientSocket_DataReceived>d__3.MoveNext()

Output log

FTP Server IP Address: ftp.mozilla.org with port 21
FTP Command Channel Initailized
FTPServer -> 220-
220-   ftp.mozilla.org / archive.mozilla.org - files are in /pub/mozilla.org
220-
220-   Notice: This server is the only place to obtain nightly builds and needs to
220-   remain available to developers and testers. High bandwidth servers that
220-   contain the public release files are available at ftp://releases.mozilla.org/
220-   If you need to link to a public release, please link to the release server,
220-   not here. Thanks!
220-
220-   Attempts to download high traffic release files f
FTPServer -> rom this server will get a
220-   "550 Permission denied." response.
220 
FTPClient -> USER anonymous
FTPServer -> 331 Please specify the password.
FTPClient -> PASS m@m.com
FTPServer -> 230-
230-   ftp.mozilla.org / archive.mozilla.org - files are in /pub/mozilla.org
230-
230-   Notice: This server is the only place to obtain nightly builds and needs to
230-   remain available to developers and testers. High bandwidth servers that
230-   contain the public release files are available at ftp://releases.mozilla.org/
230-   If you need to link to a public release, please link to the release server,
230-   not here. Thanks!
230-
230-   Attempts to download high traffic release files f
FTPClient -> PWD
FTPServer -> rom this server will get a
230-   "550 Permission denied." response.
230 Login successful.
FTPClient -> PASV
FTPServer -> 257 "/"
FTPServer -> 227 Entered Passive Mode (63,245,215,46,199,76)
FTP Data Channel IPAddress: 63.245.215.46, Port: 50951
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

========================================================================================================================

Confidential FTP URL which required authentication

System.Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WinPhoneFtp.FtpService.FtpClient.<PrepareDataChannelAsync>d__2b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WinPhoneFtp.FtpService.FtpClient.<FtpClientSocket_DataReceived>d__3.MoveNext()

Output log

FTP Server IP Address: --CONFIDENTIAL-- with port 21
FTP Command Channel Initailized
FTPServer -> 220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
FTPClient -> USER --CONFIDENTIAL--
FTPServer -> 331 Please specify the password.
FTPClient -> PASS --CONFIDENTIAL--
FTPServer -> 230 Login successful.
FTPClient -> PWD
FTPClient -> PASV
FTPServer -> 257 "/"
FTPServer -> 227 Entering Passive Mode (173,193,219,177,156,29)
FTP Data Channel IPAddress: 173.193.219.177, Port: 39938
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I also tried below given code which works on Windows 8 but not on Windows Phone 8

```
var ftpURL = "ftp://ftp.url.com";
var request = WebRequest.Create(ftpURL + "/" + file_name.ext);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "pwd");
request.Method = "STOR";

byte[] fileBytes = null;
using (var stream = await objStorageFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
    using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
    }
}

var requestStream = request.BeginGetRequestStream(async a =>
{
    var requestStreamEnd = request.EndGetRequestStream(a);
    await requestStreamEnd.WriteAsync(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    await requestStreamEnd.FlushAsync();
}, request);

var respo = request.BeginGetResponse(b =>
{
    var res = request.EndGetResponse(b);
    var aa = res.Headers;
}, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace PrepareDataChannelAsync(String channelInfo) in FtpClient class method with the following one:

```
private async Task PrepareDataChannelAsync(String channelInfo)
    {
        channelInfo = channelInfo.Remove(0, "227 Entering Passive Mode".Length);
        int start = channelInfo.IndexOf("(") + 1;
        int length = channelInfo.IndexOf(")") - start;
        channelInfo = channelInfo.Substring(start, length);

        String[] Splits = channelInfo.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        String Ipaddr = String.Join(".", Splits, 0, 4);

        //Configure the IP Address
        //Calculate the Data Port
        Int32 port = Convert.ToInt32(Splits[4]);
        port = (port * 256) + Convert.ToInt32(Splits[5]);
        logger.AddLog(String.Format("FTP Data Channel IPAddress: {0}, Port: {1}", Ipaddr, port));
        FtpDataChannel = new StreamSocket();
        await FtpDataChannel.ConnectAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName(Ipaddr), port.ToString());
        logger.AddLog("FTP Data Channel connected");
    }
```

Comment: It worked after checking if value of `(App.Current as App).ServerCurrentWorkingDirectory` is not null in `Client_FtpDirectoryListed` event in `FtpDirectoryBrowser.cs`. I am not getting `[One Folder Up]` in directory listing as it's null. Can you please help me with that? Also please explain me what you changed to make it work i.e. your answer.

Comment: The response from the FTP server was not properly parsed. Wrong port was calculated causing the connection to refuse. What you explained in your last post seems to be another bug. If you explain with more detail the problem I can help you.